# MobileFirst Cordova Upgrade

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I was using mobile first 6.2 and currently updated to 7.1.

And a file upload .js is not working after update. It was originally load by a iframe, but now the "choose file" button is not working. I guess it's about the cordova library.

However i researched the cordova library will auto update after the upgrade of mobilefirst. Or it's the problem from the cordova.js that i imported?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/cordova-android-2.3.0.js">  
......
<td id="tdChooseExistADiv" class="tdL" align="center" id="chooseExistADivTd">
    <div id="chooseExistADiv" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;left: 0;top: 0;display: block;"><img id="chooseExistAImg" src="./images/text-button/btn_choosexisting.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <input id="uploadInput" name="selectFileInput" type="file" style="z-index: 999;font-size:27px;filter:alpha(opacity=0);opacity:0;" ></input>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manually upgrade the bundled Cordova in MobileFirst Platform 7.1.

Your options are:

1. Open a PMR with your exact problem and a full reproduction so the team could look at it and patch the bundled Cordova
2. Move to MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 where you can use any version of Cordova (MobileFirst SDK is a Cordova plug-in in this release)

Comment: So when i upgrade to mobilefirst 7.1 (through mobilefirst studio), is the cordova library auto upgrade as well?

Comment: Yes it gets upgraded to the version shipped with 7.1, which is Cordova 3.6 I believe.

Comment: So where can i find the cordova.js in my project? Will there be independent js for different platforms?

Comment: It is embedded in the generated project during build time.